# Why do my interfaces in Monodevelop look different when I don't use stetic?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm converting a few projects which were using Stetic in MonoDevelop to drop that dependency. Creating interfaces by hand is not difficult at all, and the result is a more portable and understandable source code.

[image: Frame created with Stetic]

My question is... when I used Stetic, for example **Frames** were rendered with the title in bold and its subchilds indented, while now **Frames** are more similar to the ones present in Windows, with a border surrounding the whole thing. You can see that happening in the Properties frame of the following picture, for example.

[image: Frames created programmatically]

I don't really care, I mean, I even like it more that way but... why is it happening? Maybe some kind of theming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stetic, like its cousin Glade, creates some widgets with their properties set to slightly different default values than they are set to when you create them by hand.

For example, the Frame's [`Shadow`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aGtk.Frame.Shadow) property is turned off by default in Stetic, but turned on when creating by hand. The difference in spacing is probably due to Stetic sneakily inserting an [`Alignment`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Alignment) in between the Frame and its child, but you'd have to check the generated XML file to be sure.